# Displaying unqiue column names with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query joining two table

```
SELECT DISTINCT prescriptions.prescription, prescription_history.dosage
FROM prescriptions
LEFT OUTER JOIN prescription_history ON prescriptions.prescription=prescription_history.prescription
```

Now the prescriptions table has two fields primary key and prescription name and prescription_history has 4 fields where prescription name is foreign key to prescriptions.
To make this a little more clearer.

```
Prescriptions table:
id   prescription
1    advair
..   ....
```

and so on

```
Prescription_History
id   prescription   account_num   dosage
1    advair         989           20mcg
2    advair         567           50mcg
..   ...            ...           ...
```

and so on.

If I was to output this to create checkboxes I would like to see the prescription name once followed by the dosages:

```
Advair   Symbicort
20mcg    140/4.5
50mcg    120/4.5
```

and so on

but, instead I am getting prescription name twice followed by dosage.

```
Advair  Advair   Symbicort   Symbicort
20mcg   50mcg    140/4.5     120/4.5
```

and so on

How would I be able to display prescription name once then followed by all the dosages to that prescription. I tried using array_unique but that will only output one prescription name followed by the dosage and it disregards all other prescription names even if they are not the same

Comment: and so on? so you want to display each column per different row?

Comment: yes. display the prescription name just once and have all dosages for that prescription under it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do is link the two tables, and then iterate over them, finding each unique instance of a prescription, and find each dosage corresponding to it. One way you could do that would be to have an array with the prescription as a unique key, and then dosage/prescription history corresponding to each prescription. So you could do something like this (untested):

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT prescriptions.prescription, prescription_history.dosage, prescription_history.account_num FROM prescriptions LEFT OUTER JOIN prescription_history ON  rescriptions.prescription=prescription_history.prescription"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("MySQL-Error: " . mysql_error());
$arr = array();
while ($new = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
      if (array_key_exists($new[0], $arr)) {
           array_push($arr[$new[0]], array($new[1], $new[2]));

      } else {
           $arr[$new[0]] = array();
           array_push($arr[$new[0]], array($new[1], $new[2]));
      }
 }
```

After that, you could use a foreach loop to iterate over it:

```
foreach ($arr as $key) {
    print "Prescription: " . $key
    foreach($key as $value) {
        print_r$value;
    }
```